# Align CheckBox to the right using Bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using MVC5 and Bootstrap and I have the following code with produces a label and a checkbox. I want to align the checkbox to the right of it's div. Is there a bootstrap class for this? Or how do I do it in CSS?

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Use_Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Site.Use_Address, new { id = "checkUseAddress" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a class "pull-right" in bootstrap, try this out.