# Difficulty Aligning Bootstrap Custom Checkboxes to the Right

Tags: css, checkbox, bootstrap-4, alignment, frontend

I have a bootstrap 4 table in which I have custom checkboxes that I would like to align to the right.

For an example, please reference this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpx8hasm/2/)

I have used this method to create the custom checkboxes:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
</label>
```

So far, I have tried adding this CSS

```
.custom-control {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 0px !important;
}

.custom-control-label::before {
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.custom-control-label::after {
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.custom-control .custom-checkbox {
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

As well as adding the `.right` and `.pull-right` classes to all of the checkbox elements to no avail.

This question solves it by using `.pull-right`
[Align CheckBox to the right using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636308/align-checkbox-to-the-right-using-bootstrap)

Comment: There is no `pull-right` in Bootstrap 4 unless you have added it. Its now `float-right` utility class

Answer (score 0):

Using `.float-right` worked. Thanks @zgood